# Anchor text detected by google OCR using ARcore

Tags: android, arcore, google-vision, text-recognition

I am wondering how can I use the Google text recognition (OCR) with ARCore?
When I use the OCR sample to put some text above the detected text? It is jumping around as images are coming in. However I would like to anchor it to the text so when the camera moves, it is attached to it like ARcore

I couldn't find a way to do that? Google Lens does that

Any help or pointer is appreciated

Thank you